# Brazilian or Portuguese dictionary?

Tags: português-brasileiro

I've recently started Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu and thought I might learn some basic Brazilian as well, given the opportunity to practice with assorted Native speakers.

In getting a proper dictionary, should I definitely aim for a specific Brazilian one, or would most Portuguese dictionaries be just fine?

Also, would be great if anyone could recommend a proper English<->Brazilian (or German or Danish) dictionary iOS App (preferably offline - I find mostly 'translator'-apps, phrasebooks, courses, learning games etc)

Comment: I used and recommend the Langenscheidt Portugiesisch <> Deutsch. I used it to learn German.

Comment: I like very much the features offered by Google Translate App. You can download offline packages (around 200Mb for Protuguese, if I'm not mistaken). It allows you to enter text by typing, speaking or using the camera. Was really helpful in a recent travel I've had!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language is still called "Portuguese"; the Brazilian dialect is just the most spoken.

I suggest buying a Portuguese dictionary published in Brazil (instead of one published in Portugal). The most famous ones are Houaiss and Aurélio. Lexikon publishes a number of reference books in Portuguese, like a thesaurus and a dictionary of common expressions. A grammar book could help some.

About translators, I use (rarely) Google Translator when on-line; you could use a pocket English-Portuguese dictionary (a paper one - I don't know if there any in e-book format).

Comment: I endorse Castro Armaud's suggestions: Houaiss and Aurélio are the best Brazilian dictionaries of the Portuguese language, imho.

Comment: @Centaurus They're also better than anything coming out of Portugal...